# switch não reconhecendo ENUM como constante

Tags: java

```
public enum enumUpdateAction {
    NEW(0), CHANGE(1), DELETE(2), DELETE_THRU(3), DELETE_FROM(4);

    public int codigo;

    enumUpdateAction(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return this.codigo;
    }
}
```

...

```
switch (Eventos.get(0).getUpdateaction()) {

            case enumUpdateAction.NEW.getCodigo(): 
                ArrayEventos.add(InserirOrdenado(ArrayEventos, Ordem), Ordem);
                break;
}
```

Após criado o enum, estou tentando usar esse valor dentro de um switch (no caso, NEW corresponde a 0 e, portanto, estou tentando usar 0 dentro do case), mas recebo o erro "constant expression required". Alguém sabe me dizer o porque disso acontecer?

Answer (score 2):

Acontece pelo fato de você estar tentando comparar o código do enum com o enum em si, pois o `getUpdateaction()` retorna o enum em si, porem você tenta fazer o case com o código do enum, assim ocasionando esse erro, basta você retirnar o `enumUpdateAction.NEW.getCodigo()` e colocar `enumUpdateAction.NEW`.

Comment: Não, não. O Eventos.get(0).getUpdateaction() retorna um número de 0 a 4. Portanto, para não colocar 0, 1, 2, 3 e 4 nos cases, criei um enum, pois o número 0, por exemplo, refere-se a NEW. Portanto, não preciso ficar sempre lembrando o que cada número se refere. Compreende? O ENUM facilita nessa parte mas não estou conseguindo pegar o int o qual o NEW se refere, que é o 0. o getUpdateAction() não tem a ver com o enum.

Answer (score 1):

Um valor utilizado em um `case` precisa ser uma *constant  variable*, ou seja, uma variável `final` de tipo primitivo ou `String` inicializada em tempo de compilação, ou uma `enum`. Esse não é o caso do valor retornado pelo método `getCodigo` da sua `enum`.

Caso o método `getUpdateAction` retorne uma `enum` basta fazer isso:

Use o nome da `enum` no `case` :

```
switch(Eventos.get(0).getUpdateaction()) {
    case NEW:
        ArrayEventos.add(InserirOrdenado(ArrayEventos, Ordem), Ordem);
        break;

}
```

Caso ele retorne o código da sua `enum`, mude sua `enum` para:

```
public enum EnumUpdateAction {
    NEW(0), CHANGE(1), DELETE(2), DELETE_THRU(3), DELETE_FROM(4);


    private static final EnumUpdateAction VALUES[] = EnumUpdateAction.values();

    private final int codigo;

    private EnumUpdateAction(int codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    public int getCodigo() {
        return this.codigo;
    }


    public static final EnumUpdateAction deCodigo(int codigo) {
        for(EnumUpdateAction e : VALUES) {
            if(e.codigo == codigo) {
                return e;
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("codigo inválido: " + codigo);
    }
}
```

E seu `switch` para:

```
switch(EnumUpdateAction.deCodigo(Eventos.get(0).getUpdateaction())) {
    case NEW:
        ArrayEventos.add(InserirOrdenado(ArrayEventos, Ordem), Ordem);
        break;

}
```

Observação: por [convenção](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html), os nomes de classe em Java são escritas em *CamelCase*.